# Hybrid Mobile App Framework for reading fitness history

Tags: javascript, framework, google-apps, mobile, health

I need to create a JavaScript mobile app that will read fitness history from `Google Fit` and `Apple HealthKit`.  If the app is installed on Android it need to read from Google Fit. If the app is installed on iOS, it need to read from Apple HealthKit.

I found an article how to read from Apple Health Kit using Ionic framework. But I don’t any references how to read from Google Fit using IONIC.

Reference: [How To Make A HealthKit App With Ionic and ngCordova](https://devdactic.com/healthkit-app-with-ionic/)

Is there any hybrid app frameworks implementation examples  that can read **fitness history** from both Google Fit and Apple Health Kit?

[Google Fit - REST API](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/) says:

> The Google Fit REST API enables you to store and access user data in the fitness store from apps on any platform.